# Select all check box to run other selected boxes VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have a "select all" check box, however when all the check boxes are selected they do not get actioned.

The fields from *Sheet1* do not get imported or set to `Null`. On their own checkboxes import data from *Sheet1* into position, but do not work under master select all checkbox1 on / off commands.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub SelectAll_CHECK_BOX()
    Dim CB As CheckBox
    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If CB.Name <> "Check Box 1" Then
            CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
        End If
    Next CB
End Sub
```

And other checkBoxes have the following code with different range values and Sub names for each checkbox.

```
Sub CHECK_BOX_PRODUCT_NAME()
    Dim CB As CheckBox
        For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
            If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name And CB.Value <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value And ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value <> 2 Then
                ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 2
                Exit For
            Else
                ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = CB.Value
            End If
        Next CB
    Dim xChk As CheckBox
    Set xChk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    With xChk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 3)
        If xChk.Value = xlOff Then
            .Value = Null
        Else
            .Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is a visualization of the problem:
[image: gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding `Call CHECK_BOX_PRODUCT_NAME` to your first macro. just before End Sub.

As first macro is only checking the second box and not running the code for 2nd check box.

Comment: This was my go to command to get around the problem, however in the second macro, the line  `With xChk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 3)`  causes for the _CheckBox1_ to be treated as start of the offset.

As I have more than one tick box this method will not work.
Here is a GIF of what is happening https://i.imgur.com/8t5qzUR.gif

Unless there is a way to set the destination of the input as .Range("E6"), but not sure how to write that.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, then this is what you can do. Remove all code from 'Dim xChk' and replace it with this line of code  Range("E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")

Comment: I have tried your method with slight amendment, let me know what you think. Ill break this message into 3 subs for people future reference.

For select all button `Sub SelectAll_CHECK_BOX()

    Dim cb As CheckBox
            Call SELECTALL_OVERIDE
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
            If cb.Name <> "Check Box 1" Then
            cb.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
End If
Next cb
End Sub`

Comment: Call function Sub has to be separate otherwise doesn't work in the cycle 

`Sub SELECTALL_OVERIDE()
        If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOff Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value = clearcontent
            ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value = Date
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("E6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range("E10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
End If
End Sub`

Comment: Other check boxes code remains as above. 
Here is the CheckBoxses in Action https://i.imgur.com/AtxGusu.gif